# TCP Multipath using several SOCKS Proxys as uplink

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks, multipath

I would like to set up a server, that uses several SOCKS Proxys as uplink to the internet. All Multipath setups I found were about using "normal" uplink like LAN, Cable or DSL, but none that uses SOCKS proxys.

Has anyone ever done that or can point me to the right direction on how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you referring to multipath TCP as defined in RFC 6824? Or are you referring to piecing together a payload from multiple HTTP requests using the `Range` header?

Comment: Hi, I seriously don't care on how this will be implemented - It would be okay if it just rotates through the proxys for every request :).